# SQL query, can I order by within an case in order by?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database storing data on bones. For the spine, I need to sort the bones for their levels. If your not familiar, your spine has 7 cervical vertebrae (your neck), 12 thoracic vertebrae (your rib cage),  and 5 lumbar (lower back) and I need them to be sorted in order within each group and have each group sorted so that cervical then thoracic, then lumbar.

Vertebrae in the database have a column called "vertebral_level" where cervical are listed as C1, C2, C3... and thoracic are listed as T1, T2, T3, and lumbar are L1, L2, L3... I think you get the idea.

The problem I'm running into is that the normal ASC sort of "vertebral_level" defaults to alphabetical and so lumbar are incorrectly listed after cervical instead of after thoracic because L comes before T, and what's worse, because there are 12 levels for T, they get listed as T1, T10, T11, T12, T2, T3 ...

Now, I can fix the sort order within groups with this:

```
FROM vertebrae GROUP BY vertebral_level ORDER BY length(vertebral_level), vertebral_level ASC
```

which yields:
"C1" "C2" "C3" "C4" "C5" "C6" "C7" "L1" "L2" "L3" "L4" "L5" "T1" "T2" "T3" "T4" "T5" "T6" "T7" "T8" "T9" "T10" "T11" "T12"

Almost there, but I need to force the L levels to come after the T levels, so I tried this:

```
FROM vertebrae GROUP BY vertebral_level ORDER BY CASE
        WHEN vertebral_level LIKE '%C%' THEN 1 
        WHEN vertebral_level LIKE '%T%' THEN 2
        WHEN vertebral_level LIKE '%L%' THEN 3
        END
```

Which then lists the groups correctly but not the levels:
"C2" "C6" "C1" "C3" "C5" "C7" "C4" "T7" "T10" "T8" "T3" "T6" "T9" "T12" "T1" "T2" "T5" "T11" "T4" "L4" "L5" "L3" "L2" "L1"

So what I really want is something like this, but this doesn't actually work:

```
FROM vertebrae GROUP BY vertebral_level ORDER BY CASE
        WHEN vertebral_level LIKE '%C%' THEN 1 ORDER BY vertebral_level ASC
        WHEN vertebral_level LIKE '%T%' THEN 2 ORDER BY length(vertebral_level), vertebral_level ASC
        WHEN vertebral_level LIKE '%L%' THEN 3 ORDER BY vertebral_level ASC
        END
```

Again, that query doesn't actually work, but I think at this point you get what I'm trying to achieve. I could brute force it and make a case for each level instead of each group, but that is not the programming way. I'll do that as a last resort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
order by (case when vertebral_level like '%C%' then 1
               when vertebral_level like '%T%' then 2
               when vertebral_level like '%L%' then 3
          end),
         length(vertebral_level), vertebral_level
```

Or, you could shorten this as:

```
order by position(left(vertebral_level, 1) in 'CTL'), 
         length(vertebral_level), vertebral_level
```

The function `position()` returns the location of a substring within a string.  In this case, it is looking for the position of the first character describing the vertebra in `'CTL'`, giving you the order you want.

Or even:

```
order by position(left(vertebral_level, 1) in 'CTL'),
         substr(vertebral_level, 2)::int
```

Comment: could you explain what is going on inside  position(left(vertebral_level, 1) in 'CTL')?